# jsf 2.0 is backing session bean secure?

Tags: security, jsf, javabeans

I'm asking if the Bean (Sessionscoped, ManagedBean) is secure enough to save a variable "isAdmin = true". The user must not have a chance to change this value!

So the main question is: does the user has access to the beans (when there are no getters/setters and components on the view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be secure because it's a server side component so user have no access to it's fields except the one you make visible for him.